# Why does numpy.take() only return one value inside a tuple?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm going to make this as concise as possible.

Say I have the following list:

```
x = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
```

Getting the first tuple in this list is easy:

```
x[0]
```

This returns `(1, 2, 3)`

However, if I use:

```
numpy.take(x, 0)
```

the returned value is `1`.

Is this how `take()` is intended to work? It seems very counter-intuitive. Anyone have an explanation or workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the `axis` as 0 when you want to index along the first axis:

```
>>> np.take(x,0,axis=0)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Note that based on [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) if you don't set the axis by default, the flattened input array will be used.

Comment: In take's documentation it says: "axis : int, optional
The axis over which to select values. By default, the flattened input array is used." So if an axis is not provided it will default to flattened input array.